# Meaning of .ui-"something"

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

What is the meaning of

> `.ui-"something"`

used in CSS files of jquery Mobile. What is the purpose of it.
 Example:
When I Create a new file using dreamweaver(mobile). I get a predefined structure. 
some statements of the css file of jquery are:

```
s.ui-mobile,.ui-mobile body{height:100%background:url(images/home_main.jpg);}.ui-mobile fieldset,.ui-page{padding:0;margin:0}.ui-mobile a img,.ui-mobile fieldset{border:0}.ui-mobile-viewport{margin:0;overflow-x:visible;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body.ui-mobile-viewport,div.ui-mobile-viewport{overflow-x:hidden}.ui-mobile [data-role=page],.ui-mobile [data-role=dialog],.ui-page{top:0;left:0;width:100%;min-height:100%;position:absolute;display:none;border:0}.ui-mobile .ui-page-active{display:block;overflow:visible}.ui-page{outline:0}@media screen and (orientation:portrait){.ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:420px}}@media screen and (orientation:landscape){.ui-mobile,.ui-mobile .ui-page{min-height:300px}
```

So basically what does. .ui-page,.ui-mobile,.ui-mobile body mean.What will happen if i update some values or insert new css properties in them, where will i see the changes.

Comment: The UI prefix is used to avoid conflicts with other CSS files that would use too generic names like "Panel" or "Button", etc

Answer (score 0):

> The classes are designed to create a visual consistency across an application and allow components to be themeable by jQuery UI ThemeRoller.

http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/

Answer (score 0):

> jQuery mobile framework takes the "write less, do more" mantra to the next level: Instead of writing unique apps for each mobile device or OS, the jQuery mobile framework allows you to design a single highly-branded web site or application that will work on all popular smartphone, tablet, and desktop platforms.

Since you are writing "less" there should be a lot of things going on behind the scenes. Here JQuery Mobile is offering well styled mobile friendly controls. In order to obtain mobile friendly control with simple code for example like [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html):

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

JQuery Mobile wraps and styles you controls using JQuery and CSS. So when rendered the `select` tag is wrapped inside `<div class="ui-select">`. And to answer your question `ui-something` is just a CSS class.

Comment: but there is no class like "ui-mobile","ui-page" being called.